# Issue with structuremap scanning one class to implement multiple interfaces

Tags: generics, interface, structuremap

I am implementing a system with a request handler where there are multiple versions of a request.  I have an interface, IServiceRequestHandler, which handles request T.  Because there is a lot of shared code, I want to combine the handlers for different versions:

```
public class ARequestHandler : IServiceRequestHandler<V1.ARequest>, IServiceRequestHandler<V2.ARequest>
```

And this implements 2 different versions of the handle() method which is the only method on that interface.

However, in my structuremap registry class when I scan:

```
     Scan(a =>
     {
        a.TheCallingAssembly();
        a.AddAllTypesOf(typeof(IServiceRequestHandler<>));
     });
```

It registers ARequestHandler as an instance for V1.ARequest, but not for V2.ARequest.  So:

```
container.GetInstance<IServiceRequestHandler<V1.ARequest>>()
```

returns ARequestHandler, but:

```
container.GetInstance<IServiceRequestHandler<V2.ARequest>>()
```

throws an exception saying that no instance exists.

I don't necessarily need them to return the same instance of the handler, but I want them to return instances of the same handler type at least.  Am I missing something here?

I am aware that I can register them with separate For lines in the registry and that will work, but I will have a lot of handlers and really don't want to have to update the registry for all of them, that's the whole point of having the scan method.

This seems like it should just work, but maybe this is just a limitation of the scan method.